# Table information transferred between multiple sheets VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have one table on sheet1[bss] and data feeds into a table that is split between two sheets [actv & actv2].  I have a Range.Find function that based on bss.Range(F).Value and searches a range in actv and inputs the data in the respective row.  However, if the data is in actv2, I'm having issues on getting the code to search actv, if it's not found, go to actv2 and repeat the search.  I've tried multiple different ways and none seem to work when bss.Range(F) is in actv2.  I've done a single GoTo tag for when IsEmpty(Inputs) as well as Not IsEmpty, I've done double tags to send the loop there when if statements are true, This one is just embedded if statements:

```
Sub Roll_7300()

Dim oldactv As Worksheet
Dim oldactv2 As Worksheet
Dim actv As Worksheet
Dim actv2 As Worksheet
Dim bss As Worksheet
Dim BasisSST As Range ' Might not be used
Dim Inputs As Range
Dim Inputs2 As Range ' Sets the row for find in Activities
Dim EndRangeRE As Range
Dim EndRangeRE2 As Range ' Finds "10 Other Costs" in the input template
Dim EndRangeNRE As Range ' Finds "Recurring Costs" in the input template
Dim rngall As Range ' full used range in input template
Dim StartRangeNRE As Range
Dim StartRangeNRE2 As Range
Dim StartRangeRE As Range ' Finds "Recurring Costs" in the input template
Dim looprng As Range ' Range for the loop
Dim myRng As Range ' Range used in loop
Dim borderrng As Range ' Range for bordering
Dim BOE As Range ' Full used range in Basis of Estimate
Dim myRange As Range ' Range used in loop2
Dim BRow As Range ' Basis Row used in loop
Dim ARow As Range ' Activity Row used in loop
Dim newrow As Range
Dim newrow2 As Range
Dim FY16 As Variant
Dim FY17 As Variant
Dim FY18 As Variant
Dim FY19 As Variant
Dim FY20 As Variant
Dim FY21 As Variant
Dim FY22 As Variant
Dim FY23 As Variant
Dim FY24 As Variant
Dim actrng As Range
Dim Engineering As Range
Dim NRC As String
Dim Hyphen As Integer
Dim NREBasis As String
Dim looprng2 As Range
Dim rngall2 As Range

Set oldactv = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("7300 Part 1 Form")
Set oldactv2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("7300 Part 2 Form")
oldactv.UsedRange.Copy
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("7300 Part 2 Form")).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "7300 Part 1 Updated " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy")
Set actv = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("7300 Part 1 Updated " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy"))
actv.Paste
oldactv2.UsedRange.Copy
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("7300 Part 1 Updated " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy"))).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "7300 Part 2 Updated " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy")
Set actv2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("7300 Part 2 Updated " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy"))
actv2.Paste


Set bss = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("{Activity} Basis of Estimate")

actv.Activate
Set rngall = actv.UsedRange
Set EndRangeRE = rngall.Find(What:="10. Other Cost", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set EndRangeNRE = rngall.Find(What:="Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeNRE = rngall.Find(What:="Non-Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeRE = rngall.Find(What:="Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set looprng = actv.Range(StartRangeNRE, EndRangeRE)
Set borderrng = actv.Range(looprng, looprng.Offset(0, 3))
looprng.UnMerge
actv2.Activate
Set rngall2 = actv2.UsedRange
Set EndRangeRE2 = rngall2.Find(What:="TOTAL (Recurring and Non Recurring):  ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeNRE2 = rngall2.Find(What:="Non-Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set looprng2 = actv2.Range(StartRangeNRE2, EndRangeRE2)
looprng2.UnMerge

Set BOE = bss.UsedRange.Offset(4, 2)

bss.Activate
Do
For Each BRow In BOE.Rows
    Set Engineering = bss.Range("D" & BRow.Row)
    Set BasisSST = bss.Range("F" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY16 = bss.Range("AD" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY17 = bss.Range("AE" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY18 = bss.Range("AF" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY19 = bss.Range("AG" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY20 = bss.Range("AH" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY21 = bss.Range("AI" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY22 = bss.Range("AJ" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY23 = bss.Range("AK" & BRow.Row)
    Set FY24 = bss.Range("AL" & BRow.Row)
 actv.Activate
 Set Inputs = looprng.Find(What:="BasisSST", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
 actv2.Activate
 Set Inputs2 = looprng2.Find(What:="BasisSST", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
 If Not IsEmpty(Inputs) Then
    If Engineering = "NRE" Then
        bss.Activate
          NRC = BasisSST
          Hyphen = InStr(NRC, "-")
          NREBasis = Mid(NRC, Hyphen + 1)
        actv.Activate
          Set Inputs = looprng.Find(What:=NREBasis, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
          Set newrow = Inputs.EntireRow
            newrow.Cells(10).Value = FY16 + newrow.Cells(10)
            newrow.Cells(11).Value = FY17 + newrow.Cells(11)
            newrow.Cells(12).Value = FY18 + newrow.Cells(12)
            newrow.Cells(13).Value = FY19 + newrow.Cells(13)
            newrow.Cells(14).Value = FY20 + newrow.Cells(14)
            newrow.Cells(15).Value = FY21 + newrow.Cells(15)
            newrow.Cells(16).Value = FY22 + newrow.Cells(16)
            newrow.Cells(17).Value = FY23 + newrow.Cells(17)
            newrow.Cells(18).Value = FY24 + newrow.Cells(18)
    Else
        actv.Activate
          Set Inputs = looprng.Find(What:=BasisSST, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            If BasisSST = "1.1 Equipment" Then
              Set newrow = Inputs.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                  newrow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(1).Value = BasisSST
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(10).Value = FY16
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(11).Value = FY17
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(12).Value = FY18
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(13).Value = FY19
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(14).Value = FY20
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(15).Value = FY21
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(16).Value = FY22
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(17).Value = FY23
                  newrow.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(18).Value = FY24
            Else
              Set newrow = Inputs.EntireRow
                newrow.Cells(10).Value = FY16 + newrow.Cells(10)
                newrow.Cells(11).Value = FY17 + newrow.Cells(11)
                newrow.Cells(12).Value = FY18 + newrow.Cells(12)
                newrow.Cells(13).Value = FY19 + newrow.Cells(13)
                newrow.Cells(14).Value = FY20 + newrow.Cells(14)
                newrow.Cells(15).Value = FY21 + newrow.Cells(15)
                newrow.Cells(16).Value = FY22 + newrow.Cells(16)
                newrow.Cells(17).Value = FY23 + newrow.Cells(17)
                newrow.Cells(18).Value = FY24 + newrow.Cells(18)
            End If
    End If
  ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Inputs2) Then
    actv2.Activate
      Set Inputs = looprng2.Find(What:=BasisSST, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
      Set newrow2 = Inputs.EntireRow
         newrow2.Cells(7).Value = FY16 + newrow2.Cells(7)
         newrow2.Cells(8).Value = FY17 + newrow2.Cells(8)
         newrow2.Cells(9).Value = FY18 + newrow2.Cells(9)
         newrow2.Cells(10).Value = FY19 + newrow2.Cells(10)
         newrow2.Cells(11).Value = FY20 + newrow2.Cells(11)
         newrow2.Cells(12).Value = FY21 + newrow2.Cells(12)
         newrow2.Cells(13).Value = FY22 + newrow2.Cells(13)
         newrow2.Cells(14).Value = FY23 + newrow2.Cells(14)
         newrow2.Cells(15).Value = FY24 + newrow2.Cells(15)
  End If
Next BRow
Loop Until IsEmpty(BasisSST)

End Sub
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I've thought about doing a Select Case but haven't tried that yet.  Thanks all!

Comment: `If Not Inputs Is Nothing Then` - Find() returns `Nothing` if there's no match found.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you.  I was using IsEmpty instead of Is Nothing and it wasn't reading the same way.  Code works great now.  If you put that in an answer, I will gladly check it as answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
If Not Inputs Is Nothing Then
```

in place of

```
If Not IsEmpty(Inputs) Then
```

`Find()` returns `Nothing` if there's no match found.